# FTP client for Microsoft IIS Serve ? (Microsoft Ftp protocol)

Tags: ftp, iis

is there any ftp client for mac, allowing me to work with Microsoft IIS server ?
In particular I need to handle permissions on files and folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just *cannot* change file permissions on a IIS server. As far as I know, it does not support such a feature.

Comment: ok, thanks. So let's say I cannot rename files I've recently uploaded. What should I do ?